# change to colour of polygon plot and add legend

Tags: r, plot, colors, range, polygon

Follow up question from [Assign colours to values and plot horizontal bars in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974629/assign-colours-to-values-and-plot-horizontal-bars-in-r/54974916?noredirect=1#comment96710105_54974916)

with all the data values, how can i change to following code such that the colour coded on hmin2 bar switches. the left side of the line should be blue and the right side should be red.

```
FullRange = range(dataframe123, na.rm=TRUE)

BoxRanges = lapply(dataframe123, range, na.rm=TRUE)


plot(NULL, xlim=FullRange, ylim=c(0,3),  yaxt="n", xlab="Value", ylab="")
abline(v=19.293)
axis(2, at=(0:2)+0.4, labels=c("hmin1", "hmin2","hmin3"), 
lty=0, las=2)

for(i in 1:3) {
polygon(c(BoxRanges[[i]][1], BoxRanges[[i]][1], 19.293, 19.293), 
    c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="red")
polygon(c(19.293, 19.293, BoxRanges[[i]][2], BoxRanges[[i]][2]), 
    c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="blue")
}
```

In addition, how do i add a legend to the plot indicating the what the colours represent?

Red represents a negative change in parameters and the blue represents a positive change in parameters.

[image]

Been stuck for hours. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be add `polygon` for `hmin2` outside the loop. In order to add the legend, you should increase the plot area (`xlim` and `ylim`), so the legend will be visible.

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(FullRange[1]-1, FullRange[2] +1), ylim=c(-1,4),  yaxt="n", xlab="Value", ylab="")
abline(v=19.293)
axis(2, at=(0:2)+0.4, labels=c("hmin1", "hmin2","hmin3"), 
     lty=0, las=2)

for(i in c(1,3)) {
  polygon(c(BoxRanges[[i]][1], BoxRanges[[i]][1], 19.293, 19.293), 
          c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="red")
  polygon(c(19.293, 19.293, BoxRanges[[i]][2], BoxRanges[[i]][2]), 
          c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="blue")
}
i = 2
polygon(c(BoxRanges[[i]][1], BoxRanges[[i]][1], 19.293, 19.293), 
        c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="blue")
polygon(c(19.293, 19.293, BoxRanges[[i]][2], BoxRanges[[i]][2]), 
        c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="red")

legend(x = 20, y = 4.5, legend = "negative changes",
     border = NULL, fill = "red",
     bty = "n",
     bg = "n")
legend(x = 20, y = 4, legend = "positive changes",
       border = NULL, fill = "blue",
       bty = "n",
       bg = "n")
```

---

[image]

#### Edit

If you want to add a title to your plot you must use `main` inside `plot`. To add a label to your line, you can use `text`:

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(FullRange[1]-1, FullRange[2] +1), ylim=c(-1,4),  yaxt="n", xlab="Value", ylab="", main = "Range of H min values with parameter changes")
abline(v=19.293)
axis(2, at=(0:2)+0.4, labels=c("hmin1", "hmin2","hmin3"), 
     lty=0, las=2)

for(i in c(1,3)) {
  polygon(c(BoxRanges[[i]][1], BoxRanges[[i]][1], 19.293, 19.293), 
          c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="red")
  polygon(c(19.293, 19.293, BoxRanges[[i]][2], BoxRanges[[i]][2]), 
          c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="blue")
}
i = 2
polygon(c(BoxRanges[[i]][1], BoxRanges[[i]][1], 19.293, 19.293), 
        c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="blue")
polygon(c(19.293, 19.293, BoxRanges[[i]][2], BoxRanges[[i]][2]), 
        c(i-1,i-0.2,i-0.2,i-1), col="red")

legend(x = 20, y = 4.5, legend = "negative changes",
       border = NULL, fill = "red",
       bty = "n",
       bg = "n")
legend(x = 20, y = 4, legend = "positive changes",
       border = NULL, fill = "blue",
       bty = "n",
       bg = "n")
text(x = 17.5, y = -0.9, labels ="19.293", col = "black", cex = 0.9)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! As an extension, could I ask how to add a title "Range of H min values with parameter changes" to this plot and label the vertical line "19.293"? Thank you. @patL